# Why won't GNU find work recursively on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, gnuwin32

I have the full gnuwin32 installation on my Win7 box.  From the shell (cmd.exe), I can execute

```
c:\gnuwin32\bin\find.exe .
```

from a directory and get a list of all the files recursively.  What I am trying to do is find all files with filenames ending in `.rej`.  I would expect one of these to work:

```
c:\gnuwin32\bin\find.exe . -name "*.rej"
c:\gnuwin32\bin\find.exe . -name '*.rej'
```

but the first one only gives me one result (in the working directory), and the second gives me no results.  In contrast,

```
ls -R | grep rej$
```

gives me many, many results ending in `.rej`.  What am I missing?

Comment: If you don't have any other criteria, you could just run from the command line: dir *.rej /s/b

Comment: @jftuga Thanks -- I'll keep that in mind.  In this case, I do need to do something with the files, though I can still use xargs in some incarnation, I'm sure.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995493/gnuwin32-find-exe-expands-wildcard-before-performing-search. No definitive answer there though...

Answer (score 1):

I never found a good answer regarding anything I can do to make gnuwin32 find work, but I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995493/gnuwin32-find-exe-expands-wildcard-before-performing-search/3996353#3996353) with a workaround.  Specifically, using the nearly-decade-old find.exe from [UnxUtils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/) seems to work.

Comment: Cygwin's find also appears to work just fine (at least on my Win7 x64 box).

Comment: I found useful http://christianlong.blogspot.com.au/2011/01/using-gnu-tools-for-find-and-replace-on.html